# I need to wait until an activity completes before proceeding, but only sometimes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My application starts with `InitActivity` that checks for login status, calls `LoginActivity` accordingly before proceeding to some logic.

I know I can use the `startAcivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` to ensure `LoginActivity` completes before doing `doSomeMainLogic()`, but my `if` check throws  a curve in it. If I do this:

```
public class InitActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myapp.LOGINACTIVITY");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                doSomeMainLogic();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

how do I get `doSomeMainLogic()` to fire if the user is already logged in?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class InitActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myapp.LOGINACTIVITY");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
        else {
            doSomeMainLogic();  // this part is added
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                doSomeMainLogic();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something better than repeating the call in two different places, but I guess that works.